# How to change the sort order of the Past iterations to descending in TFS backlog/board?

Tags: tfs

My team is using TFS2017 and we have some 100+ past iterations (sprints) in our backlog/board. (I'm talking about Past, Current & Future iterations). We're only interested in 5-6 most recent Past iterations and scrolling to the end of the list is generally annoying.

Is there any way to change the sort order of the past iterations to descending?

If this isn't possible, is it possible to create a new group/item/list/whatever besides Past, Current and Future, called Old iterations (or something like that)?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: All the past iterations are from the same year or from few years?

Comment: Different years

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reduce the number of iterations on the "Past" section you can configure in the team settings to see only the iterations of the current year.

Press on the Gear icon when you on your team page --> Work --> Press on "Change" near the "Backlog iteration".

[image]

After that, you will see only the iteration from the current year and the scrolling not will be so annoying...

[image]